# Removing utm source via php / regex

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
$before='http://www.urchin.com/download.html? utm_source=google&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=product';
    $after = preg_replace('[?]utm_source=.*/','', $before);
 echo $after;
?>
```

Hi all,

How can I remove UTM tracking from URL via PHP/Regex in the above code example?

New to PHP so please explain your answer.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Got a bit closer but still getting errors.

Answer (score 4):

```
$url = strtok($url, '?');
```

You can read more about `strtok` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php).

**Update:** If you need to remove only `utm_` params, you can use regular expression, e.g.:

```
$url = preg_replace( '/&?utm_.+?(&|$)$/', '', $url );
```

Note: This regex will remove any `utm_` parameter from your URL.

Comment: Thanks .. it works but it also works on all urls where ? is involved               `<?php
     $url='http://www.urchin.com/category/gaming?page=1';
     // Return a clean URL without UTM - i.e. this part    http://www.urchin.com/download.html
$new_url = strtok($url, '?');
echo $new_url;
 
?>`

Comment: See my updated answer. If you found a solution, please accept any answer.

Comment: If the url contains utm_ before the actual query arguments, this will also be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use strtok to get the url as you like

```
$url = strtok($url, '?');
```

Comment: Thanks .. it works but it also works on all urls where ? is involved               `<?php
     $url='http://www.urchin.com/category/gaming?page=1';
     // Return a clean URL without UTM - i.e. this part    http://www.urchin.com/download.html
$new_url = strtok($url, '?');
echo $new_url;
 
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out:

```
<?php
$before='http://www.urchin.com/download.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=product';
 $after = preg_replace('/[?]utm_source=.*/','', $before);
 echo $after;

?>
```

Comment: this will remove all query parameters, not just utm_source

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution how to remove all UTM params from URL including hash UTM parameters:

```
<?php

$urls = [
    'https://www.someurl.com/?utm_medium=flow&red=true&article_id=5456#omg&utm_medium=email',
    'https://www.someurl.com/#utm_medium=flow&utm_medium=email',
    'https://www.someurl.com/?articleid=1235&utm_medium=flow&utm_medium=email',
    'https://www.someurl.com/?utm_medium=flow&articleid=1235&utm_medium=email',
    'https://www.someurl.com/?utm_medium=encoding%20space%20works&encoding=works%20also'
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo rtrim(preg_replace('/utm([_a-z0-9=%]+)\&?/', '', $url), '&?#') . PHP_EOL;
}
```