# how can i append utm_source and utm_medium in all url from blog content

Tags: php, laravel, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Assume I have the below text in the database.

```
$str = 'Test text http://hello-world.com Test text  http://google.com/file.jpg?google=1 Test text https://hell.o.wor.ld/test?qwe=qwe Test text text text http://test.test/test hello all how are you I hope you all are fine ';
```

Now for this text, I want to add below utm_source and medium for all URL.

```
$utmUrl = "utm_source=source&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mycamp";
```

I already know that I can find all URL and do str_replace() but I want to do it with

> preg_replace()

let me know if anyone knows any other solution

**here the problem is some URL already have ? mark in URL so there I need to apped URL with & and where there is no ? there I need to append with ?**

Comment: May be it can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647970/4575350

Comment: @sta i want to append i don't want to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit Suggested by [joy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3782543/joy)

Something like this.

```php
$re ='/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/im';
$str = 'Test text http://hello-world.com Test text  http://google.com/file.jpg?google=1 Test text https://hell.o.wor.ld/test?qwe=qwe Test text text text http://test.test/test hello all how are you I hope you all are fine ';
$utmUrl = "utm_source=source&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mycamp";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach ($matches as $match)
    $str = preg_replace('%' . $match[0] . '%', $match[0] . (strpos($match[0], '?') !== false ? '&' : '?') . $utmUrl, $str);
var_dump($str);
```

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/EPf8t)

Edit: With [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```php
$re = '/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/im';
$str = 'Test text http://hello-world.com Test text  http://google.com/file.jpg?google=1 Test text https://hell.o.wor.ld/test?qwe=qwe Test text text text http://test.test/test hello all how are you I hope you all are fine ';
$utmUrl = "utm_source=source&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mycamp";
$str = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($match) use ($utmUrl) {
    return $match[0] . (strpos($match[0], '?') !== false ? '&' : '?') . $utmUrl . ' ';
}, $str);

var_dump($str);
```

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/35csn)

> Old Answer.

Something like this.

```php
$re = '%(https?://.*)\s%mU';
$str = 'Test text http://hello-world.com Test text  http://google.com/file.jpg?google=1 Test text https://hell.o.wor.ld/test?qwe=qwe Test text text text http://test.test/test hello all how are you I hope you all are fine ';
$utmUrl = "utm_source=source&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mycamp";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach ($matches as $match)
    $str = preg_replace('%' . $match[1] . '%', $match[1] . (strpos($match[1], '?') !== false ? '&' : '?') . $utmUrl, $str);
var_dump($str);
```

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/pnu3j)

Edit: With [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```php
$re = '%(https?://.*)\s%mU';
$str = 'Test text http://hello-world.com Test text  http://google.com/file.jpg?google=1 Test text https://hell.o.wor.ld/test?qwe=qwe Test text text text http://test.test/test hello all how are you I hope you all are fine ';
$utmUrl = "utm_source=source&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mycamp";
$str = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($match) use ($utmUrl) {
    return $match[1] . (strpos($match[1], '?') !== false ? '&' : '?') . $utmUrl . ' ';
}, $str);

var_dump($str);
```

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/5SepA)

Comment: I know this way but i don't want to do a loop and all is it possible with preg_replace_callback or directly throw regex?

Comment: $pattern = '/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/im';

i have used this pattern to find URL inside anchor tag as well